# Select según números de Tupla

Tags: python, django, django-models

No me devuelve respuestas al hacer una consulta según números indicados por una tupla:

```
tupla = [1,3,5,7,9,10,12,13,15,17]
Pregunta.objects.filter(numeroPregunta=tupla)
```

¿O debería ser algo así como?

```
tupla = [1,3,5,7,9,10,12,13,15,17]
Pregunta.objects.filter(numeroPregunta=tupla[0] and numeroPregunta=tupla[1] and numeroPregunta=tupla[2] and numeroPregunta=tupla[3] and numeroPregunta=tupla[4] and numeroPregunta=tupla[5] and numeroPregunta=tupla[6] and numeroPregunta=tupla[7] and numeroPregunta=tupla[08 and numeroPregunta=tupla[9] and )
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que funciona es utilizando __in:

```
tupla = [1,3,5,7,9,10,12,13,15,17]
Pregunta.objects.filter(numeroPregunta__in=tupla)
```